# Catch Unhandled Exception in RunWorkerCompleted

Tags: c#, task, backgroundworker

Assume I have part of code like following:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
   var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
   backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted +=  (sender, args) =>  throw new Exception("Catch me if you can...");
   backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
});
```

Which event handler can catch this unhandled exception?
I tried with 1- DispatcherUnhandledException, 2- TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException, but cannot handle this.

Comment: A Backgroundworker _in_ a Task.Run?? _Bad_ Idea to begin with. The observed behavior being one of the various reasons why.

Comment: @Fildor OP did say, `"Assume"`, but something makes me believe that's not an assumption.

Comment: I knew about this, but I have a package that does this in the code.

Comment: `but I have a package that does this in the code`, then it's not an *assumption*. If you don't have control over this, quit using it; who knows what other kind of garbage may exist. Otherwise, re-think of what you're doing with this code.

Comment: _"but I have a package that does this in the code"_ - a 3rd party? Really? - Looks fishy.

Comment: ^^ so, if that's inside a 3rd party package, there's not really much you can do about it. The only options I see is : whatever that package does - a) code it yourself b) find a better package.

Comment: So, what do you think, note that I simplify my question to more understandable, if you think there isn't any way to catch this type of unhandled exception, tell me about that.

Note that we can show the exception with AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, but we cannot catch it.

Comment: What do you mean you can "show" but you cannot "catch"? - But anyway - and this is only my _opinion_ - if I found such a code in a library I am using, I'd stop using it. And file a bug report on top.

Comment: As you know we can e.Handled = true inside the ApplicationDispatcherUnhandledException and e.SetObserved() inside the TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException

Comment: @Fildor It so complicated than what you see in the question

Comment: All that just adds to the feeling that this library should be replaced.

Comment: It seems like they tried to make it "async Task-Compatible" and failed miserably at it.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for your time, I will feedback these messages to the 3rd Party.

Answer (score 2):

You should catch the event in the `RunWorkerCompleted` callback where it actually occurs:

```
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted +=  (sender, args) => 
{ 
    try {
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception) { ... }
}
```

If you can't modify the callback for some reason, you should be able to catch the exception thrown from the `Task` by hooking up an event handler to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event.

Beware that the only meaningful thing you can/should do in this kind of "last resort" event handlers is to log the exception and shut down the app.

Exceptions should be caught and handled where/when they occur.